# Lua - Download via http and https (Lua 5.1 embedded)

Tags: lua

I’m sure this is not a unique question about Lua 5.1 (especially an embedded instance, where you can’t install modules, your only options is pure Lua files/reference, therefore I can’t install something like luacurl ). I’ve seen this matter referred to in various SO places, and tried them, but I can’t seem to find a fix to make an https file download request work in this particular Lua environment..

To give you an example, the code below aims to download 2 different files, the `http` call works fine, returning a 200 code, but the `https` one doesn’t, it doesn’t return anything ?

Both targets can be access directly via the browser..
Please could some highlight what I’m missing in the https call to make it work?

```
print("--------DOWNLOAD http---------")

local http = require("socket.http")
local body, code = http.request("http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CCROQ8vUEAEgFke.jpg")
print(code)
if not body then error(code) end
local f = assert(io.open('mnt/nas/webtest1.jpg', 'wb')) -- open in "binary" mode
f:write(body)
f:close()

print("--------DOWNLOAD https---------")

local https = require "ssl.https" --luasec
local body, code = https.request("https://u.cubeupload.com/jbcooper/16146313918060.jpg")
print(code)
if not body then error(code) end
local f = assert(io.open('mnt/nas/webtest2.jpg', 'wb')) -- open in "binary" mode
f:write(body)
f:close()
```

As requested, the following returns nothing at all..

```
local https = require "ssl.https" --luasec
print(https.request("https://u.cubeupload.com/jbcooper/16146313918060.jpg"))
```

If it helps, if I run the following it returns `0.4`

```
local https     = require("ssl.https") 
local httpsVersion = string.sub(https._VERSION,1,3)
print (httpsVersion)
```

Comment: What does `body` and `code` return for you? Try calling `print(https.request("<url>"))` to see all the return values and maybe add them to your question.

Comment: Hi @DarkWiiPlayer, added your specific ask into the question, but it too returns nothing, no error, no other message/response - nada ?

Comment: You are seeing the error `"sslv3 alert handshake failure"` because Lua 5.1 does not support `sslv3`. You need to use Lua 5.3

Comment: @MikeV. SSLv3 is ancient. It doesn't make sense that 5.3 would support it when 5.1 doesn't.

Comment: Still nothing reported if I update that line to `if not body then print(error(code)) error(code) end` also, checking my luasec version `local httpsVersion = string.sub(https._VERSION,1,3)` it shows 0.4 ?

Comment: because _VERSION   = "0.4.*" , see in \Lua\5.1\lua\ssl\https.lua

Comment: Thanks @Mike V, do you have the full url for the location you suggested, i cant seem to find it ? And to ask what is likely to be my follow on question, how can i update it if i need a later version ? Or what alternative is there for embedded systems?